# TeXnicCenter MakeIndex and BibTeX error: Compile not working

Tags: compiling, texniccenter

This might seem like a duplicate but from what I can tell it's not. I have looked at the prior pages and tried the solutions offered with no change in results.

My project works fine on my desk top and compiles when I hit ctrl+f7, however now I am using a laptop with all files copied over to my laptop. The project  won't run on the laptop but it will on the desktop. I believe this is an issue with some setting however I have tried the prior setting adjustments in other postings with no improvement. This is the error I get in my output:

```
Build Output:
latex> This is pdftex, Version 3.1415926-2.40.13 (MikeTeX 2.9)
latex> entering extended mode
latex> (C:Users\TOTALNUBE\Dropbox\LameProject\WriteUp\Latex\TEST.tex
MakeIndex> Couldn't find input index file Test nor Test.idx.
MakeIndex> Usage:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTex 2.9\miktex\bin\makeindex.exe [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-pum] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Latex-Result: 0 Error(s), 0 Warnings(s), 0 Bad Box(es), 0 Page(s)
BibTex-Result: 0 Error(s), 0 Warning(s)
```

When I change my file to not include any bibtex reference I get the  same error. When I go to build->define output profiles and change the Latex to PDF to no longer use makeindex I still get an error (just no ref to MakeIndex. When I update the command line arguments in the same menu to be `"%tm" -s myIndex.ist. myIndex.ist`   I still get an error. My "build output"does not seem to run through each command as it only shows the error and nothing else.

Comment: Can you show the complete output profile you're running that is causing this output? By the way, `MikeTeX 2.9` seems strange...

Comment: That's the problem This is the only output the only other line is

Comment: ------------------Output Profile:Latex -> PDF---------------- That's it. No other output is made.

Comment: What happens if you move the files to a directory outside Dropbox? Also, is this a case-sensitive file system?

Comment: Same Result when I move it to the desktop or the my documents folders.  My file does not include any drive references (i.e. all files are included in the same folder as my .tex file), would case matter?

Comment: I still have a problem when they are on the desktop.